# Make image take full height of flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that is 100vh (minus the fixed nav height).

```
<section class="container">
```

Inside this container I  have some text:

```
 <div class="text">
    <p>title</p>
 </div>
```

Which can be of any length as the content is dynamic.

Below this text I have an image:

```
 <div class="image">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/a6/64/d1a664bca214bf785a293cbc87950fc4.jpg">
 </div>
```

The image needs to fill the rest of the 100vh (- nav height) container.

I use:

```
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    ....
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20pspusz/)

The issue I am having is that I need the image to be the height of the rest of the space.

How can I do this? In my fiddle, if your screen is small it is being cut off and if your screen is large it does not fill the space. Height: 100% fails to work, making it too large.

Flex solutions only please, no table tricks - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the image container (`.image`) a flex container with `height: 100%`.

You can then fine-tune the image's aspect ratio and alignment with `object-fit` / `object-position`.

```css
nav {
    position:fixed;
    background:grey;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}

main {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background: green;
    border: 3px solid brown;
}

.text { background: yellow; }


/* ***** NEW ***** */
.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
} 
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<nav>Nav</nav>
<main>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="text"><p>title</p></div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/a6/64/d1a664bca214bf785a293cbc87950fc4.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="text"><p>hello</p></div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/a6/64/d1a664bca214bf785a293cbc87950fc4.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/20pspusz/2/)

Note that the `object-fit` property is not supported by IE. For more details and a workaround see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127590/3597276

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you wanted, but if you move the image to a div and use it as a background, you can get the desired effect.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a5trtrz/1/)

HTML:
    
      Nav

title

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
   <div class="imageWrap">
     <div class="image"></div>
   </div>
</section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
main{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background: green;
    border: 3px solid brown;
}
.imageWrap {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.image {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/a6/64/d1a664bca214bf785a293cbc87950fc4.jpg)
}
.text{
    background: yellow;
}
```