# In addition to scaling horizontally, can I scale a div and its contents vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure;

```
<body>
    <div id="splash">
      <img /> <!-- 512x512 -->
      <progress></progress>
      <img /> <!-- 512x512 -->
    </div>
</body>
```

And this css;

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#splash {
    max-height: 100%; /* does nothing */
}

#splash img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This results in the entire div scrolling to fit within the width of the browser window.  Currently this also scales the div in height, pushing the contents below the bottom bounds of the browser window.

Is it possible to also scale the div vertically such that its contents shrink so no part of it drops below the bottom bound of the browser window?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvr1xupu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael_B's answer pointed me in the right direction, however I ended up going with something that doesn't rely on `object-fit` being supported.

It required adding a surrounding `div` to the `progress`, and limiting the height of the images to an estimate of the space I expect them to take up, in this example, 45%.

#### [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f6053qp/2/)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#splash {
  height: 100%;
}

#splash img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 45%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" />
    <div>
      <progress></progress>
    </div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body { 
    margin: 0;                /* 1 */
}

#splash { 
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;            /* 2 */
    flex-direction: column;   /* 2 */
}

#splash > img {
    min-height: 0;            /* 3 */
    object-fit: contain;      /* 4  (also try `cover` value) */
    width: 100%;
}

progress {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" />
    <progress></progress>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" />
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uhg3csa/4/)

Notes:

1. [Remove default margins on `body` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html) (which can cause scrollbars)
2. [Establish vertical flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)
3. [Enable flex items to shrink past content size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
4. [Force images to respect aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127590/3597276) (Note that `object-fit` is not yet supported by IE and Edge. For workaround options see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127590/3597276)).

Answer (score 1):

Your percentages don't work because `html` does not have a defined `height`. Use `100%` too.

```css
html, body, #splash {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#splash img {
  max-height: 48%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
progress {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" />
  <progress></progress>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" />
</div>
```

You can achieve more flexibility using `calc()` or flexbox.

Comment: This solution removes the horizontal scaling.