# How to upscale image to always cover div while keeping its aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like my inline images to behave like `background-size: cover;` While using the new property [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), which does a great job, I would like to provide a fallback.

I have created the basic setup for this fallback below. The only problem is, that I need jQuery/Javascript to choose weather the image needs to be either: `width: 100%; height: auto;` or `height: 100%; width: auto;`. How can I do this?

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  var div = $(this);
  var image = div.find('img');
  
  // if image does not cover the div, change its css to { height: 100%; width: auto;}
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightblue;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Both divs should be covered by their images, while keeping the aspect ratio:

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x100">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x600">
</div>
```

Comment: I have previously posted some fallbacks here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37127590/3597276

Comment: @thanks Michael_B. Primož Cigler seems to be a real good lightweight solution :)