# CSS: Get inline image to use 100% of width and height of container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a solution without having to use `background-image`, but being able to use an inline `<img>`.

I would like to make it so that if the image container's dimensions are not the same as the image, the image will still fill the **width** and **height** of the container, cropping whatever part it has to.

Also, if a part of the image is smaller than the container, it will stretch over 100% to fill the container.

In the example below, I have a huge image that can easily fill the width and height of the container. The container is a different aspect ratio from the image, so I end up with blank space, either horizontally or vertically. I want to fill that container no matter what, even though part of the image will be cropped away.

```css
class[*='container'] {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.container img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}
.container-1 {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
.container-1 img {
  object-fit: cover; 
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.container-2 {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
}
.container-2 img {
  object-fit: cover; 
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Original image:</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://themetry.com/wp-content/uploads/pug.jpg" />
</div>

<p>Container 1:</p>

<div class="container-1">
  <img src="https://themetry.com/wp-content/uploads/pug.jpg" />
</div>

<p>Container 2:</p>

<div class="container-2">
  <img src="https://themetry.com/wp-content/uploads/pug.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.container-1 img {
    object-fit: cover;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
class[*='container'] {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.container img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}
.container-1 {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
.container-1 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container-2 {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
}
.container-2 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Original image:</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://themetry.com/wp-content/uploads/pug.jpg" />
</div>

<p>Container 1:</p>

<div class="container-1">
  <img src="https://themetry.com/wp-content/uploads/pug.jpg" />
</div>

<p>Container 2:</p>

<div class="container-2">
  <img src="https://themetry.com/wp-content/uploads/pug.jpg" />
</div>
```

Since you're already using `object-fit`, I used it in my answer, as well. Just keep in mind it's [not supported by IE / Edge](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit). Here are some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127590/3597276