# Why do images display incorrectly inside a grid on older devices (which supposedly have full grid support)?

Tags: css, ios, safari, css-grid

First, some simplified code and expected properties. This:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Broken image in grid</title>
  <style>
    .App {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .Grid {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      display: grid;
      justify-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: blue;
      grid-template-columns: 0.25fr repeat(3, 1fr) 0.25fr;
      grid-template-rows: 0.25fr repeat(3, 1fr) 0.25fr;
    }

    .Circle {
      display: block;
      height: 90%;
      width: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      grid-row: 3;
      grid-column: 3;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="App">
    <div class="Grid">
      <img
        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAzdSURBVHic7d15jF1lGcfx79wOndK9nSmllNKWlmJCW3Y3FlkVxLpGjRhUFjVIhKgEJC4gGMWEqKyCon/gEiWQoMgiIPuSEra2/FHoMoVWGsp0pi0zJdOZKf7x3Nu5vfu5Z3nfe87vkzzpzJ17znl73/Pc97xned82JC6dwLyi2B/oyr9eiA5gSv79Y4EJ+Z8HgF35n7cDg8BWoCf/71ZgM/AG0A1sAHpj+59kWJvrAqTATGAJcDiwGFgKLAQmJ1yOHcAaYFU+VuZjS8LlSBUlSDBjgA8AxwHH52O+0xLVtxl4EXgaeAZ4ntHWSepQgtS3CDgTOAM4gdHDoFY1ADwJPAA8iLU6Ig0bA5wM3ASsA95PeawFbgROAnLhPz5Joxx2uHQ98Bbud1pX0QPcAZyGkkWAOcCV2Nkg1zunb7EB+ClwYLMfrrSmMcBngX8Dw7jfEX2P4fxn9Zn8ZycpNRH4FvAa7ne6Vo1u4HJgasDPXjx2AHAt0If7HSwt0Qv8EpgVoB7EM11YYuzE/Q6V1hgEbkOJ0lI6gauwWzRc70BZiX7sDODM+tUjrnQAl6HEcBnbgEux+8rEI8uwC16udxCFxRrgizVrTBJxKPAI7ncIReV4CDikau1JbNqBS7BjX9c7gaJ2vIf1CXXYlZAjgBdwX/GKYLEC+GCF+pSItAPXoKvfrRzDwNX5upQIzcOeZ3BdwYpoYjnqm0TmPOBd3FeqItrYAXwdado44HbcV6Qi3rgD2BcJZA7WDLuuPEUy8RL+P7rsjdOxB3dcV5oi2XgHOBWp6XxsQAHXlaVwE8PAhUiZNuxikusKUvgR16NHfvfoAP6G+0pR+BV3oc47E4CHcV8ZCj/jcWASGTUVG8jMdSUo/I7ngelkzHR0GlfReLwEzMABFyMrdgGPYePYijTqVWxAv54kN5r0mYIp2HCXSg4JajH27M+0JDeaZIKMB+4Fjk5wm5IuhwP3Y0M4JSKpBBmHDT52QkLbk/T6MHAPdnkgdkkkSBt20+HJCWxLsuFU7CbH2PvQSQwl+St0+4BE7zDswatH49xI3AlyAZYgInE4EZtB64W4NhBnE3U61qHS45USpyFscqNYWpK4EuQgbNqvrpjWL1KsFzgGG1w7UnF00scBd6PkkORMx/a5yG9ujCNBbsayWSRJRwK3ui5EPefh/r4dRbbjHCIUZR9kAfAyGb49WbzQDxxFRLP3RnWI1Q78BSWHuDcR+CuwTxQri+o6yM+AsyNal0hYs4ER4ImwK4riEOtY4Dk0waP4ZRj4EPYsSdPCJkg79sTXkSHXIxKHFdgX+FCzKwj7rX8F8NWQ6xCJy/7YsLXPNruCMC3IIixDx4VYh0jc3gOWYjOQBRbmLNYtKDnEf/sCNza7cLMJ8jk0TKS0jjOAs5pZsJlDrLHYA/Sa30FayVrsufbBIAs104J8DyWHtJ6FwEVBFwragnQB64DJQTck4oFt2C1RvY0uELQFuQwlh7SuqcAPgiwQpAWZAawnwSFXRGIwAByMPapbV5ALhb/AngEWaWVjsYbh4Ube3GgLMhs7C6DrHpIGO7FW5O16b2y0D3IxSg5Jj/HAdxt5YyMtyCTgTayDI5IWfdjgIv213tRIC3I+Sg5Jn2nAN+q9qV4LMgZ4HTteE0mbbuyi90i1N9RrQZah5JD0mg98stYb6iXIN6Mri4iXau7jtQ6xDgQ2oEdpJd2GgXnA/yr9sVYLcgFKDkm/dmp01qu1IDmsA3NQDAUS8U03dhPj+6V/qNaCHI+SQ7JjPjZzVZlqCfKl+Moi4qWK+3ylQ6wcsAmYFWtxRPyyGTsxtbv4xUotyEkoOSR7ZgHHlb5YKUE+H39ZRLz0hdIXKiXIGQkURMRHZft+aYIswk53iWTRoZTs/6UJcmZyZRHx0ieKfylNEB1eSdbt1UgUn+Ztxx4i0aAMkmX92LMiw7B3C3IkSg6RicCSwi/FCVJ2Dlgko/bkghJEpNyeXCjug2zChvcRybqN5G/WLSTI/ti9KCJiZgJbCodYS12WRMRDi2G0D7KkxhtFsmgpKEFEqlkCShCRapbAaCd9O5r3Q6RYHzC9DegEehwXRsRH03LYmEAiUm5eDhvRQUTKzc8Bc12XQsRT83LYVXQRKTczh03tLCLlunLYWSwRKdepFkSkuq4cMN11KUQ81ZlDj9mKVDMhh02sLiLlOpQgItWNVYKIVNfRho3/o6nWRMqN1JvlViTTcsAu14UQ8dSgEkSkOiWISA27lCAi1Q3msNGsRaTcQA7Y6roUIp7qyaEBG0Sq6VELIlLdVrUgItX15IC3XZdCxFNbcsAG16UQ8VS3EkSkuu427JFbddRFyk3NAb3Y4NUiMqoP2F643X2ty5KIeGgNjM4PssphQUR8tBKUICLVrILRBFnpsCAiPloFozNMzQC2uCuLiHf2A94ptCDvAJscFkbEJ29iOUHxoA3PuimLiHeeLvxQnCDPOCiIiI/25IISRKTcnlxoK3qxHbt6qMGsJct2YLdfjcDeLcgw8JSLEol45HHyyQF7JwjAg4kWRcQ/e+VAW8kfDwFeT64sIt5ZAKwv/FLagqwB1iVaHBF/rKYoOaA8QQAeSKYsIt4p62JUSpC7EyiIiI/uKn2htA8CljQbgQNiL46IPzYBc4HdxS9WakF2o1ZEsudOSpIDKidI4c0iWVJxn690iAWWOOuxJkck7dYDC4H3S/9QrQXZDfwpzhKJeOSPVEgOqN6CAByIjZmlCT4lzYaxI6W3Kv2x1iSem4D/xFEiEY/cT5XkgNoJAvD7aMsi4p3ba/2x1iEW2OHVa9j9KSJp043dfzhS7Q31WpAR4IYoSyTikeuokRxQvwUBmAC8AXRGUSIRT/QCBwEDtd5UrwUhv4I/RFEiEY/cRJ3kgMZaEIBZ2G3w+4YpkYgnBoCDaWAsuEZaEIDNwK1hSiTikZtpcKDERlsQgC7skvykZkok4ol+7KxsQwnSaAsCNtnnLc2USMQjvyHAMLtBWhCwM1nrgCkBlxPxQR/W99jW6AJB77N6DxgCPh5wOREf/BB4IsgCQVsQgLHY0PCLmlhWxJXVwFLsC75hQfogBbuAS5tYTsSl7xMwOaC5FqTgIeD0EMuLJOV+4KxmFgyTIIcAK9DFQ/HbTuzQqqnx3sI8DNWLPXl4aoh1iMTtCuC+ZhcO04KAjQi/HDgq5HpE4rACOJYm+h4FzXTSiw0D36bOLcMiDgwD5xIiOSCa583fyq/nYxGsSyQqVwH/CLuSsIdYBe3Ak8BHIlqfSBjPYF/YoY9sokoQsEv4LwOTI1ynSFDbgSOwEXlCC9sHKbYeuDjC9Yk04ztElBwQ/ZhXK7DxtHRWS1z4HXBtlCuM8hCroAOb6/DYGNYtUs1yrN8xGOVK40gQgDnAi8CMmNYvUmwLcDQ22GGkouyDFNsIfAU7Fy0SpyHgy8SQHBDvuLvd2DWST8e4DZGLiHE+m7gHpn4Z65OcEPN2JJuuxgZ/a2ltwJ+x4eUViqji78TXh07cOOAR3H+oinTEQ9iRSeySzMDx2BTTJya4TUmf57AxEfqT2FjSTdRk4L/AMQlvV9LhFeAUbHSSRLg4husCHgMWO9i2tK5VwMnA1iQ3Gtd1kFp6sMOs5Q62La3pJazlSDQ5XJsCPI37Dp/C73iKDA9UOB6bB9F1JSj8jEeBiWTcWHSdRFEed2KXB5zyYYrnEeCe/M8nOSyH+OMG4AJ0L1+Zc7GRG11/eyncxBA2CIjUcAp2+7LrylIkG2+jI4iGzcaumLquNEUy8QIwFwmkA7ge95WniDduw07USJPOwUaqcF2RimhjG3A2Eom52LhbritVEU08h80TKBFqB67EznS4rmBFczEE/AQ/Li+k1lLgedxXtiJYvILu4k5MO3AJ8C7uK15RO3YCl+frTBK2AHsIy/VOoKgc92FD0opjpwGv4n6HUFi8BnyqZo1J4vbBJmrsw/0OktXoxQ5996lTV+LQJOyYdxvud5isxLvYmLjTGqgf8UQnVmkDuN+B0hoD2N0OMxusE/HQTODn2OOarneotEQPcA2wX4B6EM91AF8DVuN+B2vVWI/1MSYE/OylhYwBlgH/wh7Icb3T+R5DwD/zn5mugGfMbODH2Dej6x3Rt1gH/Ag4oOlPV1LlMGxm1HW43zldxSas0308KRr3VqKVw0aj/y12wcv1Tht3rAZ+jSWFi3HSpMUdjE0MeS+wA/c7dNjYjvW/LgTmR/g5pZKa0WDGAEuwb9uP5v+d47RE9W3EBuh7FhuE7VUimD88K5Qg4XUBh2OJszj/8wKSv6rcB6wFVmLj2K7K/9yTcDlSRQkSn6nAPOwwZi4wC0umzqLowIbVzGH3LxVGEezHTq/uxg6JBrELnYXoATYDb2BT3XXn3ycR+z+U1fyv7Ab2iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
        alt="circle" class="Circle" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Should render like this (+ chrome dev tools overlay to see grid):

[image: Circle with dev tools overlay]

However, on some older Apple devices, e.g. iPhone 6 and iPad 6, it renders like this:

[image: 90 percent]

I don't have access to an Apple computer, so I can't use Safari dev tools, but as best as I can tell, the image is ignoring the grid and rendering relative to the outer container instead. Weirdly, it isn't at 90% of the outer container, but rather somewhat less. Setting height to 100%, we see the following:

[image: 100 percent]

which is clearly 100%, but at 50%, we get:

[image: 50 percent]

which, without actually measuring, looks closer to 25% to me.

It's also worth noting that e.g. a div with background color renders correctly, i.e. this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Working div in grid</title>
  <style>
    .App {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .Grid {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      display: grid;
      justify-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: blue;
      grid-template-columns: 0.25fr repeat(3, 1fr) 0.25fr;
      grid-template-rows: 0.25fr repeat(3, 1fr) 0.25fr;
    }

    .Square {
      background-color: black;
      height: 90%;
      width: 90%;
      grid-row: 3;
      grid-column: 3;
      z-index: 1;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="App">
    <div class="Grid">
      <div class="Square" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

renders correctly on all tested devices as this:

[image]

To summarize, here are the results on all devices that I have ready access to:

- All: correct div
- iPhone 6 (iOS 12.5.3, Software 12.5.2), Safari & Chrome: broken img
- iPhone XR (iOS & Software 14.5.1), Safari: correct img
- iPad 6th gen (iPadOS 14.5.1, Software 13.3.1), Safari: broken img
- iPad 7th gen (iPadOS 14.5.1, Software 14.4.2), Safari: correct img

What is going on here? I have no real design experience, so css is admitedly a little bit black magicky to me at times. I'd be more than happy to learn that this is programmer error, but whatever the case, help would be much appreciated. Also helpful would be a description of how to help myself next time, e.g. is there some way I could have looked up device differences on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) or the like. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773109/231316

Comment: @ChrisHaas that answer is very helpful and does indeed sound like the "why" of it. It's a bit surprising that Safari's interpretation of the height spec isn't consistent across devices that are still under support, but I'm willing to accept that it's nonetheless true. That said, the answer (use flexbox instead) doesn't work for me, because I actually require a 2d grid for my application. Anywhere you could point for help with that?

Comment: Actually, I think nested flexboxes (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644245/12162258) might be the solution. It feels like the code will be significantly less clean, but if it works... I'll try and report back

Answer (score 0):

As in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773109/231316) @ChrisHaas pointed out, this seems to have been due to Safari, at least on older devices, having a different interpretation of the height spec that doesn't consider grid height sufficient for a parent reference. As such, percentage height is meaningless vis-a-vis the grid, and the image scales based on the grid container instead (or something close to it. See the comparisons in my original question above).

This doesn't explain everything in my question, especially why the `div` scales correctly but the `img` does not, but it did lead to a working solution using nested flexboxes thanks to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644245/12162258) linked from the answer noted above. There's **a lot** more markup doing it this way, and I think the code is much less intuitive, but it does work on the older devices mentioned in the question, so that's something.

NB for anyone trying to use this solution, I'm not certain that using `height`/`width` percentages as I have below is the best solution. I tried `flex-grow` at `1` for the cells and `0.25` for the borders, which constructs the correct empty "grid," but that solution also allows the image to grow the center box instead of being constrained by it, so I had to throw it out. Someone with deeper flexbox knowledge than me might be able to point out a way to make that angle work.

Anyhow, here's the working code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Working image in grid</title>
    <style>
      .App {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .Grid {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .Grid-Row {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }

      .Top-Bottom {
        height: 25%;
      }

      .Cell {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .Left-Right {
        width: 25%;
      }

      .Circle {
        width: 90%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="App">
        <div class="Grid">
          <div class="Grid-Row Top-Bottom"></div>
          <div class="Grid-Row">
            <span class="Cell Left-Right"></span><span class="Cell"></span
            ><span class="Cell"></span><span class="Cell"></span
            ><span class="Cell Left-Right"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-Row">
            <span class="Cell Left-Right"></span><span class="Cell"></span
            ><span class="Cell"
              ><img
                src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                alt="circle"
                class="Circle"
              /> </span
            ><span class="Cell"></span><span class="Cell Left-Right"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-Row">
            <span class="Cell Left-Right"></span><span class="Cell"></span
            ><span class="Cell"></span><span class="Cell"></span
            ><span class="Cell Left-Right"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-Row Top-Bottom"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

UPDATE: It turns out that there's a better solution. I observed initially that a `div` in the grid would be correctly placed and sized. It turns out that using such a `div` to wrap the image also works, so with a small amount of extra markup we can still use CSS Grid.

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Grid {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  background-color: blue;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr repeat(3, 1fr) 0.25fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.25fr repeat(3, 1fr) 0.25fr;
}

.Cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.Circle {
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Working image in div in grid</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="App">
        <div class="Grid">
          <div class="Cell">
            <img
              src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              alt="circle"
              class="Circle"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```