# Spacing between rows wider than intended

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I have a grid layout (display: grid) that is 4 cells wide. When there's only two rows, the spacing between them is larger than it's supposed to be. If there's three or more rows, everything looks like it should. This is basically what the html looks like:

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-grid">
     <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
     <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
     <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
     <!-- and so on... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

These are my css rules:

```
.thumbnail-container {
    overflow: scroll;
}

.thumbnail-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 8px;
}

.thumbnail-grid-cell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
```

Just to clarify:

This is what it looks like with 2 rows:

[image: grid with 2 rows]

This is is what it looks like with 3 rows:

[image: grid with 3 rows]

The column spacing is always correct.

Comment: why is that a problem? And if so, why is that only a problem when there's two rows? The parent for the cells has no width specified.

Comment: Because you have set the grid columns to `auto` width....If you want them equal, set them to `1fr`

Comment: I've tried to set the grid-template-columns to 1fr, and that didn't make a difference. I tried to set it to all kinds of values, and the spacing between the rows is still the same. Given the fact that this specifies the width, and nothing else, that actually makes sene.

Comment: `1fr` **will** fix it - see - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NMVLQe

Comment: Your example only demonstrate columns spacing, and that is not the problem. I'll add some pictures to clarify what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to come to a solution here because there isn't enough data to reproduce the problem. But here's what it may be:

Because you haven't explicitly defined any rows in the grid, rows are implicitly added and their heights are set by default to [`grid-auto-rows: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).

The `auto` and `1fr` values will stretch to occupy empty space in the container.

So the gap you're seeing in your image #1 is *not* a gap between rows.

[image: grid with 2 rows]

The actual gap between rows is 5px, as set by your `grid-row-gap` rule.

*There is an appearance of a gap* between rows because the grid items are not filling the height of the row.

Look at it this way:

- There are two rows.
- The container is set to `height: 250px`.
- The rows divide the height equally, so each row is 122.5px tall each (after subtracting the 5px grid row gap).
- But the items inside those rows are set to `height: 100px`.
- So there's a 22.5px gap between the bottom edge of the items and the bottom edge of the row.

When you have three rows, this free space is needed, and the rows close in.

Here are three potential solutions:

1. Instead of `auto` or `fr`, try `grid-auto-rows: min-content`
2. Remove the `height: 250px` on the container; this sets the height of the container to the height of the content (i.e., `height: auto`)
3. Add `align-content: start` to the container

For more details see these posts:

- [Why does CSS Grid layout add extra gaps between cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46616289/3597276)
- [Reduce space between rows in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47285595/3597276)

Comment: both 'grid-auto-rows: min-content' AND 'align-content: start' did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.thumbnail-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  margin: 8px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.thumbnail-grid-cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-grid">
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-grid">
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="thumbnail-grid">
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail-grid-cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```