# Make image fit CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid in which I position images but they doen't fill the entire space they are given.

I hope the image below illustrates the problem good enough. As we can see the top image as well as the right one don't fill the rows they are assigned to. What causes this and how can I fix it?

Code is like that:

```
 <section class="wrapper">
   <div class="one">
     <img class="img" src="images/lorem/ipsum.jpg" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="two">
     <img class="img" src="images/lorem/ipsum2.jpg" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="three">
     <img class="img" src="images/lorem/ipsum3.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
 </section>

 .wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
   grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
   grid-gap: 20px;
   height: 100vh;
 }

.one {
  grid-column: 2 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
} 

.three {
  grid-column: 5 / 7;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should include the HTML so we can reproduce the problem. These posts may help: [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46616289/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47285891/3597276).

Comment: maybe the minmax set at 150px is too much ? can you clarify with your HTML structure and image sizes to demonstrate your issue ... maybe it also have to do with HTML ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I did add the HTML. The fix Yan suggested kinda solves the problem of the gaps but now when I resize the images get cut

Comment: for image you can take a look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/ (similar effect than background-size) . The thing is that for the image to fill entire cell grid you will have to cut off part of it or stretch them. if their size size doesn't fit at first. Do you want to stretch them ?

Comment: No I don't want to stretch them. They should keep their aspect ratio. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem to this before , the simple solution is to set the height or width to 100% for the img elements to fill their container. Then to set the object fit property to cover for better cropping. You don't even need div containers for your images. Like this:

The grid container will take care of the positioning of the cells.

```css
img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: The modern answer!

Answer (score 9):

add one div to wrap your image, then set image style to 
.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

Comment: did you mean .div-name img{width:100%; height:100%;}

Comment: HTML (with CSS Grid areas):
<graph> 
    <div>
        <img class = "img" src="data:image/png;base64,{{html_graph}}" alt="Location Graph" />
    </div>  
</graph>
CSS:

graph {
  grid-area: graph;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.img{
        max-width: 100%; height: auto

Comment: still the image goes over on the height

Answer (score 5):

This is normal because images are preserving their aspect ratio.

A good way to solve this common problem is to set the image as a CSS-background parameter in a div in your grid instead of an `<img>` tag in html, such as background: url('http://link-to-your-image/image.jpg') and use `background-size: cover;` on the same element.

This way, the picture will fill out all the space that is attributed to it.

Comment: Ok, well thanks that helps. I'm surprised. Is this the only way you can solve this issue for images you want in your CSS Grid?

Comment: 'fit-content: cover' is similar to the background image stuff but for img objects

Answer (score 0):

Try background-size: 100% 100% and background-size: cover or fit

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using React with inline styles:

```
<div 
    style = {{
        gridArea: "image",
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageFromImports})`,
        backgroundSize: "contain",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the rules to dynamically resizing images within a css grid. They are:

1. Every nested grid element of the parent grid must have `min-height: 0` set, including the `img` tag itself
2. The `img` tag must also define `max-width: 100%`
3. The immediate grid parents of the `img` tags must also have `min-width: 0` set for the `align-` and `justify-` properties to work correctly

Here is sample code that will work:

```js
// parent
<div css={{
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateRows: "max-content 1fr",
    height: "50vh",
    maxHeight: "50vh",
}}>
    <header></header>

    <div css={{
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateRows: "3fr 2fr",
      minHeight: 0,
    }}>
        <div css={{
          display: "grid",
          minHeight: 0,
          minWidth: 0,
        }}>
            <img
                css={{
                  maxHeight: "100%",
                  minHeight: 0,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                }}
            />
        </div>

        <div css={{
          display: "grid",
          minHeight: 0,
        }}>
            {imgs.map(img => 
                <div css={{
                  display: "grid",
                  minHeight: 0,
                  minWidth: 0
                }}>
                    <img
                        css={{
                          maxHeight: "100%",
                          minHeight: 0,
                          borderRadius: 10,
                        }}
                    />
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding min-height: 0; to my img tag solved the issue for me fully. Thank you very much for your post! Best, I

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Strange. Using `height` and `min-height` together solved this for me. Didn't need `object-fit` either. I can't tell why.

Answer (score 0):

Browser preserving aspect ratio does appear to be the reason why this is not as straightforward as you might think.

I was able to get the image to fill a grid cell by nesting the IMG in a parent DIV and then simply applying the following to the *class on the image*:

I prefer this over using a background for accessibility reasons.

```css
.image {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  border-radius: var(--default-border-radius);
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a demo:

```css
:root {
  --grid-gutter: 25px;
  --grid-max-width: 1440px;
}

.image {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: var(--grid-gutter);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: var(--grid-max-width);
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: var(--grid-gutter);
  padding-right: var(--grid-gutter);
  padding-top: 0;
  row-gap: var(--grid-gutter);
}

.large-span-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.large-span-8 {
  grid-column: span 8;
}
```

```html
<aside class="four-eight grid">
  <div class="large-span-4">
    <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text</h4>
    <p class="copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <div class="">
      <a href="#" class="link">Learn About It</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-span-8">
    <img class="image" src="https://placehold.co/600x600" />
  </div>
</aside>
```