# Image tags not contained in flex container without using divs or set width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently trying to have images in a `flex` container within a single row. I noticed that the images 'ignore' the container's width and overflow the page unless you wrap each image tag with a `div` or add `min-width: 1%` to the images.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="[url]">
  <img src="[url]">
  <img src="[url]">
</div>
```

CSS, images overflowing the page:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container img {
  flex: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Fixing overflow issue:

```
.container img {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 1%; /* width of images adjust to the parent container */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I was just wondering if this is normal behaviour or I have some CSS that is causing this.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container img {
  flex: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container.fix img {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 1%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://scontent.fmla3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12140762_1159067420823544_4471328164031495581_n.jpg?oh=e9255c0340cca64e7f51bb114bc25f9c&oe=5AC9097D" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider1.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="container fix">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://scontent.fmla3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12140762_1159067420823544_4471328164031495581_n.jpg?oh=e9255c0340cca64e7f51bb114bc25f9c&oe=5AC9097D" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127384/why-isnt-object-fit-working-in-flexbox

Comment: We could do with a @Michael_B explanation here.

Comment: An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that, by default, flex items cannot be smaller than the size of their content. The images are children of the flex container, making them flex items. Their minimum size will be the natural width of the image, causing an overflow in this case. You can override the default with `min-width: 0` (or `min-width: 1%`, like in the question). https://jsfiddle.net/5wxg7nes/1/  @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)