# Why does flexbox stretch my image rather than retaining aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flexbox has this behaviour where it stretches images to their natural height. In other words, if I have a flexbox container with a child image, and I resize the width of that image, the height doesn't resize at all and the image gets stretched.

```css
div {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KAthy7g.jpg" >
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

What causes this?

Comment: In Firefox and IE works fine. In Chrome you can fix with `align-self:flex-start`  in the image. I don't know why, maybe the default value in chrome is stretch.

Comment: Also adding height: 100%; to the img fixes the problem, I would like to know why it stretches the image too.

Comment: @blonfu, the default value in all browsers is `align-items: stretch` / `align-self: stretch`. If you add a border around each item and remove `wrap`, you'll notice all items stretch in all browsers: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLXBVx?editors=1100

Comment: Ok.I learn this but with images work differently in chrome and the others browser. Chrome don't respect the aspect ratio if you don't define the height.

Comment: @blonfu, Yes. No question there are browser inconsistencies and more granular levels.

Answer (score 512, accepted):

It is stretching because `align-self` default value is `stretch`.
Set `align-self` to `center`.

```css
align-self: center;
```

See documentation here:
[align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

Comment: Yes but the others browser mantaining the aspect ratio in the images. Chrome nor applies flex-basis in img

Comment: I think `align-self: start;` may be a stronger answer because images should vertically align to the TOP of their containers (not center) like any styleless image (no css) would. Either way, both answers fix the stretching. So it depends on what OP wants of course - just didn't get that 'vertically centered' impression from OP's post.

Comment: If you don't define a width on an image and it's in a flex-container, it will stretch to 100%. `align-self: [flex-start, center...others]` will prevent the image from taking 100% of the flex-containers width. `align-self:center` fixes it of course, but if you want your image to start from the beginning or end of container use `align-items: flex-start or flex-end`

Comment: You can also put `align-items: center` (or whatever alignment fits your needs) on the parent.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: <img src="FILE.jpg" class="" style="align-self: center; width:100vw; height:70vh;">

Comment: I cant really understand why adding a align-self: anyvalue; really solves the problem. Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 25):

The key attribute is `align-self: center`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img.align-self {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Without align-self:</p>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NFBYJ3hs.jpg" />
    <p>With align-self:</p>
    <img class="align-self" src="http://i.imgur.com/NFBYJ3hs.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the CSS settings below: `contain` or `cover` is most popular

```
.my-img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

or

```
.my-img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Adding `margin` to align images:

Since we wanted the `image` to be `left-aligned`, we added:

```
img {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Similarly for `image` to be `right-aligned`, we can add `margin-right: auto;`.  The snippet shows a demo for both types of alignment.

Good Luck...

```css
div {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
hr {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%
}
img.one {
  margin-right: auto;
}

img.two {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Flex Box</h1>
  
  <hr />
  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="one" 
  />
  
  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="two" 
  />
  
  <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is stretching because align-self default value is stretch. 
there is two solution for this case :
 1. set img align-self : center 
OR 
 2. set parent align-items : center

```
img {

   align-self: center
}
```

OR

```
.parent {
  align-items: center
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while making my navigation bar, but none of the above worked for me.

My solution was adding `height: 100%` for the image.

If you're aligning the items horizontally, add `width: 100%` instead.

EDIT: Chrome seems to add this value by default now, but you'll need to add this for compatibility.

Comment: Yes, Thank you! This worked for me. But I had to put the image in a wrapper, set the height and width of the wrapper then set the image itself to 100% width.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, my solution was adding `flex-shrink: 0;` to the image.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with a Foundation menu.  `align-self: center;` didn't work for me.

My solution was to wrap the image with a `<div style="display: inline-table;">...</div>`

Comment: It's about flexbox though.

Comment: This _is_ a solution for flexbox.  The image and div are inside a flexbox container.