# Why images are getting stretched inside Foundation 6.4 Cards Component

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I was working on a layout using Zurb Foundation for Sites 6.4. I want to have 3 cards per row in large view and 2 columns in small view. Images are getting stretched when I am viewing in large screen.

here is the Codepen : https://codepen.io/coolsaint/pen/oGWmLq

I don't want the images to be stretched and remain to their original dimension in large view and there should not be any margin in between them.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" />

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x align-center">


    <div class="cell shrink small-6 large-4">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell shrink small-6 large-4">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell shrink small-6 large-4">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the images are stretching because of flexbox, here is a similar issue: [Why does flexbox stretch my image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609642/why-does-flexbox-stretch-my-image)

You could also try a strategy with a background-image instead of an `<img>`.

Do you want to preserve the aspect ratio of 320x180 (56%)?
Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/mcordeiro/pen/YrQNNm

Comment: Please use the edit button to expand your answer and explain how it solves OP’s issue.

Comment: @Marcelo Codeiro Did you try it in the Codepen? because it doesn't work. Images are still stretched.