# Flexbox stretching image horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm running into a weird inconsistency with an image on my website. It's structured like this:

```html
<div class="intro">
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/headshot.jpg" />
</div>
```

```css
.intro {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.intro>img {
    width: 11rem;
    height: 11rem;
    border-radius: 6rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    align-self: center;
}

.intro>div {
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

After a hard reload in Chrome 74, it renders like this (wrong):

[image: incorrect render]

But then if I inspect element and toggle any of the `img`'s properties off and on again, it renders like this (correct):

[image: correct render]

I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609642/why-does-flexbox-stretch-my-image), which suggested adding `align-self: center;` to the `img`, but that hasn't helped.

You can see the issue live here: https://leonoverweel.com/. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: It loads fine on my comp

Comment: make the image inside a div ..there is some known issue when image is a flex item

Comment: Does adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.intro>img` css rule fix the problem?

Comment: That seems to fix it @PiotrWicijowski, thanks. I've added it as answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Anyway, this behavior seems to me like a bug in Chrome, but having such a safeguard in your css will not hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `flex-shrink: 0` to `.intro>img` seems to fix this, as per [Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10311733/piotr-wicijowski)'s comment.