# Bootstrap card image distorted in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap v4 cards in my layout and unfortunately, the images are distorted in Internet Explorer 11. It seems that IE completely ignores the `height: auto` attribute given by the `img-fluid` class. Is it necessary to apply a custom height to the card images? However, the cards render perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. Interestingly, if I change the engine to IE 10 (in the F12 console), the problem is gone.

As images with class `img-fluid` which are not wrapped by cards are displayed respecting their original ratio, I think the problem corresponds to the card layout.

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/1.jpg" alt="Step 1" width="600" height="400" />
            <div class="card-block">
              <h3 class="card-title">Step 1</h3>
              <p class="card-text">Text 1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/2.jpg" alt="Step 2" width="600" height="400" />
            <div class="card-block">
              <h3 class="card-title">Step 2</h3>
              <p class="card-text">Text 2</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/3.jpg" alt="Step 3" width="600" height="400" />
            <div class="card-block">
              <h3 class="card-title">Step 3</h3>
              <p class="card-text">Text 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha so you should expect various issues.

The issue with image height in IE 11 has already been identified and you can track it here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21885

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, but when I wrapped the content of the card in a `<a>` tag to make it clickable and it fixed itself, but the height of the card was wrong in IE11, I fixed that by adding `height: 100%` to the `<a>` tag :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="/document" style="height:100%;">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="foo.jpg">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4>doc number 4</h4>
                <p class="card-text">yada yada</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want your card to be clickable, you could replace the `<a>` by a `<div>` (I haven't tested it).

Comment: Yes, replacing the `<a>` with `<div class="h-100">` is also working.

Comment: Adding h-100 to the <a> worked for me like magic. Thank you Christophe.

Comment: Be advised: this breaks the alignment of `card-footer`s in `card-deck`s. What this (and the `div` solution by Spri) effectively does, is to kill the flexbox. You could achieve the same thing by directly setting the display of the card to `block`.
The root issue is IE11 not properly supporting images as flexbox elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822370/flexbox-on-ie11-image-stretched-for-no-reason

Answer (score 4):

Addding height:100%; can also be done to:

```
.card img{
  height:100%;
}
```

if you dont want to add another class etc to fix issues in explorer.

Answer (score 2):

the solution is to add `d-block` (display:block) to the parent div:

```
<div class="card d-block">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `overflow: hidden` for external container

Answer (score 1):

Inline styling do the magic...

eg.: `style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"`

Answer (score 1):

**This is a known issue. You can fix this by adding `width: 100%;`**

**According to docs:**

> SVG images and IE 10 In Internet Explorer 10, SVG images with
>   .img-fluid are disproportionately sized. To fix this, add width: 100%
>   \9; where necessary. This fix improperly sizes other image formats, so
>   Bootstrap doesn’t apply it automatically.

You can check the docs in this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/images/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21885) the only thing that worked for me in IE11 was adding a `height: 0.01px` to the card image.

To make it IE specific I've added the following rule:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    /* IE10, IE11 */
    .card-img-top {
        min-height: 0.01px;
    }
}
```

In my case I also have a `.card-footer` which failed to render properly in IE11 with all previous answers. I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me was to modify IE only.

Turns out it was the `card-body` text causing the most issues because it wasn't wrapping properly.

The `card` element did also need `display:block;` but again, only on IE.

No need to add **block** for other browsers, as it can affect using the `mt-auto` class or other utilities.

Here's the full solution:

```
<div class="card ie-block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" class="card-img-top" />
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="ie-wrapper"><h5 class="card-title ie-inner">Card title</h5></div>
        <div class="ie-wrapper"><p class="card-text ie-inner">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p></div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then, add the following IE10+ only CSS:

```
/* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
    .ie-block {
        display: block;
    }
    .ie-wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }
    .ie-inner {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Just added the regular old school class "img-responsive" & seems to be working fine in Chrome now.

```
<img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="images/your-image.jpg" alt="Description">
```

**Update BS version 4:**

```
img-responsive
```

is now

```
img-fluid
```