# Keep image's ratio in a flex container on height resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with image in a flex container. I want it to keep ratio when the container/window height is decreased/resized down.

**[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c68v5Lot/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg/1200px-Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Some content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you try to do it you can see that only image's height changes but width stays the same and the image is kind of stretched.

When I delete 'display: flex' from the image container, an image resizes well. I made it flex because i wanted it to be centered.

Is there a way to keep the ratio and fluidly resize image and the rest of containers?

Comment: In this `fiddle` no stretched, and width and height both resized.

Comment: Try to resize down output window.

Comment: @pedram, generally in my application I have an option that this wrapper container decreases its height when a user performs a specific action. That's why I'm talking about window resizing in this moment. When you keep decreasing height of output window you will see that width of image does not change.

Comment: You need to set  `height` free, please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c68v5Lot/1/) Is it okay for you? your image not square and you need set `auto` for `height`

Comment: @pedram Not exactly. I want to achieve effect that is visible when you set image-container's display on block, just like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c68v5Lot/2/)

Comment: @pedram But now an image is not centered. I could use other way to center this image but would like to keep things consistent with flex.

Comment: If your buggy behavoir is about IE , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822370/flexbox-on-ie11-image-stretched-for-no-reason/36828291 and your fiddle fixed ? https://jsfiddle.net/c68v5Lot/3/ Your missing rule on `img`, might just be : `flex-shrink:0;`

Answer (score 2):

Just add `object-fit: cover;` on **img** tag:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cm9ffo9a/)**