# How can I prevent flex items from shrinking in IE11 to be smaller than their content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Assuming the following markup: ([JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/btej3adw/25/))

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.space-avail-sets-height {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content-sets-height">
    <h3>This part should be as tall as it needs to be to fit the content.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="space-avail-sets-height">This part should take whatever height is remaining, and then use scrolling to view the content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit ipsum, vel, tenetur aperiam dolores a cum laboriosam omnis sint cumque beatae quis doloribus, id veniam vitae. Explicabo, libero dicta consequatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit ipsum, vel, tenetur aperiam dolores a cum laboriosam omnis sint cumque beatae quis doloribus, id veniam vitae. Explicabo, libero dicta consequatur.</div>
  <div class="content-sets-height">This part should be as tall as it needs to be to fit the content.</div>
</div>
```

What can be done to make IE11 correctly display elements who's height depend on their content? (Not worried the overflowed section here) While every other browser does it correctly, our old friend IE coughs this up onto the page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```css
.parent > div:first-child,
.parent > div:last-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

IE11, for whatever reason, needs `flex-shrink` disabled. (Probably because `min-height: auto` is the default setting on non-IE browsers, meaning that the items cannot shrink below the height of their content. But [in IE11 the default may be `min-height: 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/3597276). But then again, adding `min-height: auto` to IE11 doesn't solve the problem.)

Comment: probably the same about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822370/flexbox-on-ie11-image-stretched-for-no-reason/36828291#36828291 where MS says : *If omitted, the element's negative flexibility is "0"* which obviously is not for flex-shrink ;)