# IE11 flex:1 causes content to overflow when parent has no fixed height

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have an element which depending on the scenario can have a fixed height or a height of auto / undefined.

I need a title at the top, and a footer at the bottom, with a content area in between which should fill the available space. Using flexbox and `flex:1` works fine if the parent element has a fixed height, but in IE11 if no height is specified, the content in the element with `flex:1` will overflow.

See example here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/JymmiJUwrPxiM2qS?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

In the "Fluid height" demo, the content overflows onto the footer text. The content element (`.body`) occupies no space at all. I expect the content to dictate the height of the `.body` element.

I could have an extra class that turns off `flex:1` if there is no fixed height specified, but I won't know  this ahead of time, or have control over weather a height is specified or not.  Also I'm not looking to use any other sticky footer solutions (table layout, absolute positioning, etc)

Code from plnkr:

```html
<div class="container" style="height: 150px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <div class="title">Fixed height</div>
  <div class="body">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Fluid height</div>
  <div class="body">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.body {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  /* overflow: auto; */
}

.footer {
  opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE11 you need to reset `flex-shrink` to 0 for `.body`, Also, prefix are not needed *(i run a genuine IE11 to let you know):*

https://jsbin.com/takanicuyi/1/edit?html,css,js,output *//works with IE11*

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.body {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="height: 150px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <div class="title">Fixed height</div>
  <div class="body">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Fluid height</div>
  <div class="body">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Similar issue with img : [Flexbox on IE11: image stretched for no reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822370/flexbox-on-ie11-image-stretched-for-no-reason/36828291#36828291)